# Angular : CSS of one component is conflicting with another Component.

Tags: css, angular

My project Hierarchy is as below:

```
Component_HomePage
   |
   |---> Component_Tool1
   |        |
   |        ---> Component_Inner_01
   |
   |---> Component_Tool2
            |
            ---> Component_Inner_02
```

Obviously all Component are having different styling.

Though there are some CSS classes in `Component_Inner_01` & `Component_Inner_02` whose names are same but content is different.

For example:

Component_Inner_01.CSS having `list-group-item` class

```
.list-group-item{
    padding: 0px;
}
```

And Component_Inner_02.CSS is also having `list-group-item` but content is diff.

```
.list-group-item{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

So for the first time when i browse `Component_Inner_01` list-group-item takes padding as 0px, which is perfect.

But when i view `Component_Inner_01` page after viewing `Component_Inner_02` page, list-group-item class of Component_Inner_01 is taking padding as 10px.

I figured out the issue was in `Component_Inner_02`

Component_Inner_02's decorator having metadata `encapsulation` which is set to `ViewEncapsulation.None`

But i don't know what making CSS classes conflict with each other when having `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`, Can anybody explain ?

Comment: i suggest you read what does the `emulated` value in [the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation), so that you understand better `none` (styles will not be limited to the component with `none`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

View encapsulation means that your view is encapsulated : it means Angular adds random attributes to your tags to distinct them from one to another.

If you use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`, then your view isn't encapsulated anymore : styles don't have random attributes, and start conflicting.

If you want to stop that, remove that line from your component.

the CLI provides a global style sheet called `style.[extension]` where you can put all global styles. You don't need to deactivate encapsulation.

Comment: Makes sense ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing the line as #trichetriche said use the necessary encapsulation mechanism.

**FYI**

`ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`:  Any styles we define on a component don’t leak out to the rest of the application.
But, the component still inherits global styles like *twitter bootstrap*.

`ViewEncapsulation.Native`: Styles we set on a component do not leak outside of the components scope. 
Component is also isolated from the global styles we’ve defined for our application.

`ViewEncapsulation.None`: We are not encapsulating anything, 
the style we defined in our component has leaked out and started affecting the other components.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a wrapper element and give it an Id, use that ID to give styles for that particular component. And same for the second component also. So that the styles won't make conflict one after another.

```
<div id="component1">
    //Component1 code here
</div>

<div id="component2">
    //Component2 code here
</div>
```

Styles

```
#component1 .list-group-item {
    padding: 0px;
}

#component2 .list-group-item {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: So basically, you see that he removes the built-in encapsulation, and you offer him to do a manual one ? That's a bit counter productive ...